# Exclude characters from string before passing it to encodeURIComponent()

Tags: javascript, unicode

If a string contains character from interval `U+D800..U+DFFF` then `encodeURIComponent()` throws a `malformed URI sequence` error. I would like to eliminate those characters from a given string before passing it to `encodeURIComponent()`. How to do that?

Example:
I have a textfile encoded in UTF-16BE which contains the following hexa chars:

`D7FF D800 D801 ... DFFE DFFF E000`

I'm searching for a function which returns this string from the string above:

`D7FF E000`

So only valid Unicode characters remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `replace`/`encodeURIComponent` combo to achieve the desired result. You first need to match all the characters that do not fall in the unicode range `[0xD800..0xDFFF]` using this regex: `/[^\uD800-\uDFFF]+/g` then replace them with their encoded versions:

```
let result = string.replace(/[^\uD800-\uDFFF]+/g, match => encodeURIComponent(match));
```

**Example:**

```js
let string = "/foo/\uD7FF\uD800\uD801/bar";

let result = string.replace(/[^\uD800-\uDFFF]+/g, match => encodeURIComponent(match));

console.log(result);
```